# table with horizontal columns

Tags: html

I want to create a table with horizontal columns.
How I make `position()` values got to the `Statistics Name/TC Number` row.
And the `StatisticsName` get all the `current()` values in relevant rows.

```
<table border="1" >

                                <tr bgcolor="#006699">
                                    <th ALIGN="LEFT">Statistics Name/TC Number</th>

                                </tr>



                                    <xsl:for-each select="PcbStatistics/PcbStatisticsEntries/PcbStatisticsEntry">
                                        <th ALIGN="LEFT"><xsl:value-of select="StatisticsName"/></th>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="TcData/double">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style='padding:2px 100px 2px 2px'><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></td>
                                                    <td style='padding:2px 100px 2px 2px'><xsl:value-of select="current()"/></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                        </table>
```

Me xml looks something like this

```
<PcbStatisticsEntry>
                  <StatisticsName>Reflow Time /200C</StatisticsName>
                  <TcData>
                    <double>2.2</double>
                    <double>1.9</double>
                    <double>93.1</double>
                    <double>94.3</double>
                    <double>90</double>
                    <double>87.3</double>
                  </TcData>
                </PcbStatisticsEntry>
                <PcbStatisticsEntry>
                  <StatisticsName>Soak Time 120-175C</StatisticsName>
                  <TcData>
                    <double>2.5</double>
                    <double>1.8</double>
                    <double>2.2</double>
                    <double>1.9</double>
                    <double>93.1</double>
                    <double>94.3</double>
                  </TcData>
                </PcbStatisticsEntry>
```

etc...
Thanks for help.

Comment: Theres a rogue <th></th> that is not encased within a <tr> after the <xsl:for-each>

Comment: Er... I thought *horizontal columns* were called *rows*... You need a table in which you can horizontally insert your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use tables. You can make use of two div element floated left with 50% Width. Things will be much easier and better this way

Comment: Because this appears to be fairly straighforward tabular data so it would probably be best suited to a table no?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend nested UL lists to show your data. See this link for more details. http://www.mountaindragon.com/html/lists.htm